# GitHub actions refuses to use C++23

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, github-actions

I have following workflow file:

```
name: Build & Test (Linux)

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "develop" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        build_type: [Release]
        c_compiler: [gcc, clang]
        include:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            c_compiler: gcc
            cpp_compiler: g++
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            c_compiler: clang
            cpp_compiler: clang++

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set reusable strings
      id: strings
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "build-output-dir=${{ github.workspace }}/build" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    - name: Install Compilers
      run: >
        sudo apt update && sudo apt install gcc-13 && sudo apt-get install build-essential
    - name: Set Default Compilers
      run: >
        sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-13 100 --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-13 --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-13 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-13
    - name: Check Compiler Versions
      run: >
        gcc -v && clang -v
    - name: Install Libraries
      run: >
        sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev && cd /usr/src/gtest && sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt && sudo make && sudo cp lib/*.a /usr/lib && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a
    - name: Configure CMake
      run: >
        cmake -B ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${{ matrix.cpp_compiler }}
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${{ matrix.c_compiler }}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{ matrix.build_type }}
        -S ${{ github.workspace }}
    - name: Build
      run: cmake --build ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }} --config ${{ matrix.build_type }}

    - name: Test
      working-directory: ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }}
      run: ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }}/test/dzik_tests
```

I've tried quite a few things there as you can see so that I can compile my project, I also have this in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
```

But my GitHub actions still always fail with following for GCC:

```
Run cmake --build /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/build --config Release
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/Utils/StringManipulation.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/Utils/HostOperations.cpp.o
In file included from /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/HostOperations.hpp:25,
                 from /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/HostOperations.cpp:22:
/home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/Types.hpp:23:10: fatal error: expected: No such file or directory
   23 | #include <expected>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/Utils/HostOperations.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:153: CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

and following for Clang:

```
Run cmake --build /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/build --config Release
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/Utils/StringManipulation.cpp.o
In file included from /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/StringManipulation.cpp:19:
In file included from /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/StringManipulation.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/string:48:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/stl_iterator.h:2618:35: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category'
      { using iterator_category = iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category; };
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/StringManipulation.cpp:19:
In file included from /home/runner/work/dzik-vm/dzik-vm/src/Utils/StringManipulation.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/string:55:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.tcc:593:34: error: expected expression
      auto __r = std::move(__op)(auto(__p), auto(__n));
                                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.tcc:593:45: error: expected expression
      auto __r = std::move(__op)(auto(__p), auto(__n));
                                            ^
3 errors generated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/src/Utils/StringManipulation.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:153: CMakeFiles/dzik.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Both of which seem to indicated that C++23 is not used.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)` should be followed by `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`

Comment: Looks like you're using libstdc++ 13, are the c++23 features you want to use supported in that version? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B23_library_features Does the version of cmake you're using support c++23?

Comment: I see alternatives being used to repoint gcc to gcc-13. But what about `g++`? Your `matrix.cpp_compiler` is `g++`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I rarely use Linux so I didn't know I had to repoint g++ as well, that fixed the issue.